# Рекурсия и фишки

Tags: c++

Есть задача о фишках, необходимо ее решить рекурсией, вот условие:

> Дана полоска из клеток,
> пронумерованных от 1 до N. Разрешено
> снимать или ставить фишку на первую
> клетку или на клетку, следующую за
> самой левой фишкой. Изначально строка
> пуста. Нужно занять все клетки.
> Формат входного файла
>
> С клавиатуры вводится натуральное число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10).
>
> Формат выходного файла
>
> Требуется вывести последовательность номеров клеток, с
> которыми совершается действие. Если
> фишка снимается, то номер клетки
> должен выводиться со знаком минус.
> Количество действий не должно
> превышать 10000. Если существует
> несколько возможных решений задачи, то
> разрешается вывести любое.
>
> Примеры
> Ввод 3  
> Вывод 1 2 -1 3 1

Я решаю так:

```
void F(int n, int i, const bool first = false)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        F (n - 1, i - 1);
        cout << i << " ";
            if (!first)
                F(n - 1, 1 - n);
            else 
                F(n - 2, n - 2);
    }
}

int main()
{    
    cin >> n;

    F(n, n, true);

    return 0;
}
```

Прошу помощи, что я делаю неправильно? Знаю, что переменная first лишняя, она говорит о том был ли запущен метод из main'а. Данный код решает задачу для n = 1,2,3.
Для n = 4, он выдает
1 2 -1 3 -3 -2 -1 4 1 2 **-1**
вместо
1 2 -1 3 -3 -2 -1 4 1 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> выдает 1 2 -1 3 -3 -2 -1 4 1 2 -1
>
> вместо 1 2 -1 3 -3 -2 -1 4 1 2

А почему вы считаете, что 3 -3 правильно? Ведь вы ставите фишку, а потом сразу её убираете.. какой в этом смысл? Зачем тогда было её туда ставить?

Я написал для самотренировки рекурсию с одним параметром и у меня вышло следующее

> 1 2 -1 3 -2 4 2 1

**UPD** По просьбе трудящихся привожу свой код. Надеюсь, вы простите меня, что я написал на Java, так как мне было сподручнее. Исправить обратно на C будет совсем просто.

```
package cg;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * @author Sergey Mashkov
 */
public class Main {

    private void processCell(int cell, int N) {
        if (cell <= N) {
            printCell(cell);
            if (cell < N) {
                if (cell > 1) {
                    printNegateCell(cell - 1);
                }
                processCell(cell + 1, N);
            }
        }
    }

    private void processCells(int N) {
        if (N > 0) {
            processCell(1, N);
            processCells(N - 2);
        }
    }

    private void printNegateCell(int cell) {
        System.out.print('-');
        printCell(cell);
    }

    private void printCell(int cell) {
        System.out.print(cell);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine().trim());

        new Main().processCells(N);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Объяснение простое. Сначала мы пытаемся захватить самую правую клетку. Для этого мы берём текущую, затем берём следующую, а потом снимаем текущую. Но снимаем только если мы не захватили последнюю (если мы захватили последнюю, то это значит, что клетка за ней тоже захвачена, а раз так, то у нас захвачено две последних клетки и снимать клетку не имеет смысла). Далее, начинаем всё по новой начиная с первой клетки до тех двух последних, которые были захвачены на предыдущей итерации. И так повторяем проходы слева направо отщипывая от линейки по две концевые до тех пор, пока всё не будет заполнено. Очевидно, сложность будет N / 2 проходов, каждый проход ~2n шагов.. n уменьшается каждый раз на два.. арифметическая прогрессия получается.. вам не составит труда оценить, что для N=10 будет точно меньше 10000. Да и эксперимент подтвердит ;)

Comment: Извиняюсь, мой косяк,если не сложно, не могли бы Вы скинуть Ваш код?

Comment: К сожалению, это частичное решение, но все равно спасибо, попробую дописать.
P.S. при N = 7 в Вашем решении ответ заканчивается на 5 4 3 2 1, так нельзя

Comment: Должно быть я не правильно понял условия задачи. В таком случае, правильно ли я понимаю, что для N=4 решение "1 2 -1 3 -2 4 1 2", а для N=7 - "1 2 -1 3 -2 4 -3 5 -4 6 -5 7 1 2 -1 3 -2 4 -3 5 1 2 -1 3 1" ?

Comment: Я исправил ответ, чтобы соответствовать решению выше.

Comment: Решение для `N=4` содержит ошибку: шаг `-2` нельзя делать - первое поле пустое в этот момент.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(k,n):
  if n<= 0:
    return
  if k<=n:
    print(k)
    if k>1 and k!=n:
        print(-(k-1))
    f(k+1,n)
  else:
    f(1,n - 2)

n=int(input())
k=1
f(k,n)
```

Comment: Не похоже на C++.

Comment: Решение для N=4 содержит ошибку: шаг -2 нельзя делать - первое поле пустое в этот момент.

Answer (score 0):

косвенная рекурсия на С++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f(int n);
void del(int n){ //функция удаления фишек от 1 до N
    if(n > 0){
        del(n-2);
        cout<<-n<<" "; 
        f(n-2);
        del(n-1);
        
    }
}
void f(int n){ //функция заполнения фишек
    if(n > 0){
        f(n-1);
        del(n-2);
        cout<<n<<" ";
        f(n-2);
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    f(n);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код без объяснения идеи не наберёт очки.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить задачу потребуется три взаимно рекурсивные процедуры: `fill` решает задачу заполнения, `set` - ставит одну фишку, `clear` - стирает одну фишку.

`fill` ставит две верхние фишки и делает рекурсивный вызов:

```
                 //          n
fill(n)          // 000...0000???... ->
    set(n - 1)   // 000...0010???... ->
    write(n)     // 000...0011???... ->
    fill(n - 2)  // 111...1111???...
```

`set` ставит предыдущую фишку, ставит нужную, стирает предыдущую:

```
                  //          n
set(n)            // 000...0000???...
    set(n - 1)    // 000...0010???...
    write(n)      // 000...0011???...
    clear(n - 1)  // 000...0001???...
```

`clear` ставит предущую фишку, стирает нужную, стирает предыдущую. Очень похоже на `set`:

```
                  //           n
clear(n)          // 000...0001???...
    set(n - 1)    // 000...0011???...
    write(-n)     // 000...0010???...
    clear(n - 1)  // 000...0000???...
```

Всё вместе:

```
#include <iostream>

void write(int n) {
    std::cout << n << ' ';
}

void clear(int n);
void set(int n);

//          n
// 000...0001???... ->
// 000...0000???...
void clear(int n) {    //           n
    if (n > 0) {       // 000...0001???...
        set(n - 1);    // 000...0011???...
        write(-n);     // 000...0010???...
        clear(n - 1);  // 000...0000???...
    }
}

//          n
// 000...0000???... ->
// 000...0001???...
void set(int n) {      //          n
    if (n > 0) {       // 000...0000???...
        set(n - 1);    // 000...0010???...
        write(n);      // 000...0011???...
        clear(n - 1);  // 000...0001???...
    }
}

//          n
// 000...0000???... ->
// 111...1111???...
void fill(int n) {     //          n
    if (n > 0) {       // 000...0000???...
        set(n - 1);    // 000...0010???...
        write(n);      // 000...0011???...
        fill(n - 2);   // 111...1111???...
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if (!(std::cin >> n)) {
        return 1;
    }
    fill(n);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror fill-row.cpp
> $ echo 1 | ./a.out 
> 1 
> $ echo 2 | ./a.out 
> 1 2 
> $ echo 3 | ./a.out 
> 1 2 -1 3 1 
> $ echo 4 | ./a.out 
> 1 2 -1 3 1 -2 -1 4 1 2 
> $ echo 5 | ./a.out 
> 1 2 -1 3 1 -2 -1 4 1 2 -1 -3 1 -2 -1 5 1 2 -1 3 1
> ```